# Show field from a related entity in Sugar

Tags: php, crm, sugarcrm

I'm migrating data from Sugar 6.5 and I should create the fields for that.

I saw that several fields are originating from a related entity and displayed in the form. 
Their datatype is "Relate", but I cannot create them.

This is what I see
[image]

Is there a different way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I misunderstood your question.
As a side note n:n realtions create relationship tables with fields in them :-)

But what you seek can be done like this:

[image]

Comment: First: the many to many relationship won't create any additional field. Second: I won't to show fields from the related entity, not only the link to the other record.

Comment: misunderstood question / changed answer